# Magento 2 - How do I set up a category page?

Tags: product, category, theme, sidebar

I successfully set up my own Magento 2 store and now I want to display all the categories on the home page. Everyone is talking about some "category page" but I can't seem to find it. Is this some kind of module? Where do I start? Also I found this: https://github.com/Sebwite/magento2-category-sidebar
I followed the instructions but the sidebar isn't showing anywhere on my website.

I am stuck and I don't really know how to achieve any of this.

Comment: Not a real question as @Pixell does notbrespond to answered question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already create your categories? I.e. is your problem having the categories showing up on the website or do you have a problem in creating them?

Create a category:
In the backend, go to:

Products -> Add Subcategory -> Category Name [your category name] -> Save

If the category does not show up in frontend, check the Category Page settings:

1. Enable Category: Yes
2. include in Menu: Yes
3. Anchor: Yes